# Aplicação Web (rodando apenas em celular)

Tags: java, html, web-service, aplicação-web, android-studio

Existe algum meio onde eu consiga fazer basicamente um instalador, como se fosse uma aplicação ou jogo para celular???? Porque queria gerar um icone de acesso para o cliente sem que necessite abrir site através de navegador. Icone para acessar e navegar, não um atalho para clicar e ser redirecionado....

Exemplo : Baixo um "apk" para instalar esse meu serviço no celular do usuario, instalação normal de aplicativo para android mesmo, e assim que ele clicar sobre o icone será levado as págs e navegara normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso o que você quer existe, e chama-se PWA!

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Leia mais, e comece a dar uma estudada nesse conceito. Vale e muito a pena!

Comment: Opa muito obrigado !!! Era isso mesmo que estava procurando!!!